# Place image on page that users can refer too using "src" in an "img" tag (Django)

Tags: django

How do I place an image that people can refer to i.e via a link just like [this](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prins_Philip,_hertug_af_Edinburgh#/media/Fil:Duke_of_Edinburgh_33_Allan_Warren.jpg) ?

If I just place a normal `<img src="{% static 'media/my_img.png' %}">` in my template and inspect the site, the source is `static/media/my_image.png`.

I want to be able to refer to specific images from my webpage in an email using html like`<img src="my_page.com/logos/my_image.png>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your site url in the your context
If it is your webpage, you can use: {{ request.get_host }}
So it will become: `<img src="{{ request.get_host }}{% static 'media/my_img.png' %}">`
When generating an email just make sur you also provide the host or the request object when generating the email content and use it in the same way.

Comment: Add `{{ request.scheme }}` also (to get the protocol http / https).